# Is there there a word to describe fall out between friends without any argument or quarrel?

Tags: single-word-requests

If two people who used to be friends just stopped being friends with out any reason? Like they used to talk before but now they slowly stopped talking or contacting each other?

Comment: "fall out" typically implies some sort of conflict or disagreement. Is that required in your example (per the actual question text, I can't quite tell).

Comment: Please edit your post to do both of the following two things. First, show us which words you've already considered but discarded, along with why you found each of those unsuitable. Second, show us a few examples of how you might use this term in a broader sentence. We need to understand if you're looking for a noun or a verb or an adjective, or even something else.

Answer (score 4):

The friends **[lost touch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lose%20touch)** with each other:

> to stop communicating with each other : to no longer know what is happening in each other's lives
>
> > They were friends in college, but then they moved to different cities and lost touch.

Comment: also 'drifted apart'.

Comment: I like "drift apart" too.  It has more of the implication that the loss of contact was slow and reflective of the ebb and flow of relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The two friends have *grown/drifted apart*:

From [Cambridge Dictionary, "grown apart"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grow-apart):

> If two people in a close relationship grow apart, or if they grow away from each other, they gradually begin to have a less close relationship, usually because they no longer have the same interests and want the same things:  There was nobody else involved - we just grew apart.

and [*drift apart*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drift-apart):

> If two people drift apart, they gradually become less friendly and their relationship ends.

Note: "...becomes less friendly" here does not necessarily imply they became angry/hostile toward one another; rather the friendship weakened.